# Finding all pseudo related data within an SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement to change a "broken" computed column in a table to an identity column and as part of this work update some of the field values.  This column is a pseudo primary key so doesn't have any constraints defined against it.  I therefore need to determine if any other tables in the database contain a pseudo foreign key back to this column.

Before writing something myself I'd like to know if there is a script/tool in existence that when given a value (not a column name) can search across the **data** in all of the tables within an SQL Server database and show where that value exists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick google found this page/script:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

I don't personally know of a pretty GUI-interfaced utility that'll do it.